# how to edit the sample_ids using sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed, extract, xargs

I have a file that contain sample IDs.
I want to generate a sample participant look up table which should have two columns separated by tab. The first column should be GTEX-1117F-0226-SM-5GZZ7 GTEX-1117F
I was able to get the first ID from the file:

```
grep "GTEX" gene_tpm_2017-06-05_v8_brain_cortex.gct | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=""; printf $0 }' | xargs -n1 > ids_bed.txt
```

Now my ids_bed.txt file look like this:

```
GTEX-1117F-3226-SM-5N9CT
GTEX-111FC-3126-SM-5GZZ2
GTEX-1128S-2726-SM-5H12C
GTEX-117XS-3026-SM-5N9CA
GTEX-1192X-3126-SM-5N9BY
GTEX-11DXW-1126-SM-5H12Q
```

I want to add GTEX-1117F as the second column and so on
I tried to do this:

```
sed -re 's/(GTEX-[[:alnum:]]+)_\1/\1/g' ids_bed.txt > ids_bed_1.txt
```

but it doesn't generate the second column.
I want my final file to look like this: both the columns separated by tab:

```
GTEX-1117F-3226-SM-5N9CT GTEX-1117F
GTEX-111FC-3126-SM-5GZZ2 GTEX-111FC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use GNU `sed` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
GTEX-1117F-3226-SM-5N9CT
GTEX-111FC-3126-SM-5GZZ2
GTEX-1128S-2726-SM-5H12C
GTEX-117XS-3026-SM-5N9CA
GTEX-1192X-3126-SM-5N9BY
GTEX-11DXW-1126-SM-5H12Q
```

then

```
sed 's/\(GTEX-[^-]*\)\(.*\)/\1\2\t\1/' file.txt
```

gives output

```
GTEX-1117F-3226-SM-5N9CT    GTEX-1117F
GTEX-111FC-3126-SM-5GZZ2    GTEX-111FC
GTEX-1128S-2726-SM-5H12C    GTEX-1128S
GTEX-117XS-3026-SM-5N9CA    GTEX-117XS
GTEX-1192X-3126-SM-5N9BY    GTEX-1192X
GTEX-11DXW-1126-SM-5H12Q    GTEX-11DXW
```

Explanation: I use 2 capturing groups one for GTEX-(anything but -) and one for rest of line. I replace whole line by `\1\2` which is whole line, TAB then content of 1st group.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.7)*

Answer (score 4):

If your shown samples(last ones) are final output needed then you can simply try following `awk` should work.

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"} {print $0" "$1,$2}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting `FS` and `OFS` to `-` in `BEGIN` section. In main program printing current line followed by space, 1st field OFS and 2nd field.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk -F'-' -v OFS='\t' '{print $0, $1 FS $2}' ids_bed.txt
GTEX-1117F-3226-SM-5N9CT        GTEX-1117F
GTEX-111FC-3126-SM-5GZZ2        GTEX-111FC
GTEX-1128S-2726-SM-5H12C        GTEX-1128S
GTEX-117XS-3026-SM-5N9CA        GTEX-117XS
GTEX-1192X-3126-SM-5N9BY        GTEX-1192X
GTEX-11DXW-1126-SM-5H12Q        GTEX-11DXW
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)([^-]*-){3}.*/&\t\1/' input_file
```

Using `awk`

```
$awk -F'-' '{s=$1FS$2;$0=$0"\t"s}1' OFS="-" input_file
```

**Output**

```
GTEX-1117F-3226-SM-5N9CT        GTEX-1117F
GTEX-111FC-3126-SM-5GZZ2        GTEX-111FC
GTEX-1128S-2726-SM-5H12C        GTEX-1128S
GTEX-117XS-3026-SM-5N9CA        GTEX-117XS
GTEX-1192X-3126-SM-5N9BY        GTEX-1192X
GTEX-11DXW-1126-SM-5H12Q        GTEX-11DXW
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `awk` using your pattern matching GTEX and 1+ alphanumeric chars from the start of the string.

If there is a match, print the whole line plus the match.

```
awk 'match($0, /^GTEX-[[:alnum:]]+/) {
  print $0, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}' file
```

Output

```
GTEX-1117F-3226-SM-5N9CT GTEX-1117F
GTEX-111FC-3126-SM-5GZZ2 GTEX-111FC
GTEX-1128S-2726-SM-5H12C GTEX-1128S
GTEX-117XS-3026-SM-5N9CA GTEX-117XS
GTEX-1192X-3126-SM-5N9BY GTEX-1192X
GTEX-11DXW-1126-SM-5H12Q GTEX-11DXW
```